# Html5 audio tag flash fall back

Tags: flash, html, audio

How do you implement a flash fallback for an html5 audio tag? for example I have this audio tag

```
<div class = "div.jp-audio"><audio  class ="audio-player" name= "audio-player" src="song.mp3" ></audio></div>
```

How do I enable or create a flash fall back since not all browsers support .mp3 files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a good code snippet that has a nicely-implemented Flash callback:

```
<audio id="audioplayer" preload controls loop style="width:424px;">
    <source src="audio.mp3">
    <source src="audio.caf">
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
    if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) && ("" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
        AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer", {soundFile: "audio.mp3"});
    }
</script>
```

Here is the ref where I found it: 
[Getting HTML5 Audio Tag and Flash Fallback to Work Nicely With All Browsers](http://code.coneybeare.net/getting-html5-audio-tag-and-flash-fallback-to)

Hope it Helps!

Comment: just one example with full code needed for the library: http://pastebin.com/UueXh3SE

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/czEF9/17/) using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) & JS.

**In HTML:**

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>​
```

**In JS:**

```
var audioSupport = document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;

var swfPath = "http://www.youtube.com/v/XSGBVzeBUbk?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3";

var divID = "ytplayer";

if(audioSupport) { $("#ytplayer").append("Your Browser Supports audio"); }

else { swfobject.embedSWF(swfPath, divID, "425", "356", "8"); }
```

Comment: in the onLoad event of the page, perhaps... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Comment: can you show me a working example? do I need to provide a song.swf?

Comment: see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/czEF9/14/ ... make changes as necessary. Use a browser which does not support audio tag to see the difference in the same link.

Comment: Here try this...http://jsfiddle.net/czEF9/17/ You wouldn't have got an output in a audi supporting browser as per the old snippet.