# html5 Audio song only playing first 2 in array?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Only the first 2 of my songs are playing then nothing happens.
I am unsure why it works twice and then stops? I want it to player forever going through the array of songs.
I cannot get my rewind to work also, I want it so when you click on the rewind button the song goes to the -- on the array an if that is less than 0 it goes to the array.length song.

Globals:

```
var btnPlay = new Button(561,743,33,92);
var btnRewind = new Button(0,0,800,300); //entire canvas just to test

var song1 = new Audio("songs/loop1.mp3");
var song2 = new Audio("songs/loop2.mp3");
var song3 = new Audio("songs/loop3.mp3");
var song4 = new Audio("songs/loop4.mp3");
var song5 = new Audio("songs/loop5.mp3");
var song6 = new Audio("songs/loop6.mp3");
var song7 = new Audio("songs/loop7.mp3");
var song8 = new Audio("songs/loop8.mp3");
var song9 = new Audio("songs/loop9.mp3");
var song10 = new Audio("songs/loop10.mp3");
var song11 = new Audio("songs/loop11.mp3");
var rewindClicked = false;
var songList = [];
var currentSong = 1;

songList.push(song1,song2,song3,song4,song5,song6,song7,song8,song9,song10,song11);

var song = songList[0];
```

Rewind button clicked method:

```
function mouseClickedButtons(e)
{
alert("hi"); //works
   if(btnRewind.checkClicked())
   {
   alert("hey"); //does not
   rewindClicked = true;
     NextSong();

   }

}
```

change song method:

```
function NextSong()
{
document.removeEventListener('ended',NextSong);

if(rewindClicked ==true)
{
currentSong--;
}
else
{
currentSong++;
}

if(currentSong > songList.length);
{
currentSong = 1;
}

if(currentSong < 0)
{
currentSong = songList.length; 
}

songList[currentSong].play();
rewindClicked = false;




songList[currentSong].addEventListener('ended', NextSong);
}
```

listener:

```
song.addEventListener('ended', NextSong);
```

Button Object(I have this working in a play button so it works)

```
function Button(xL,xR,yT,yB)
{
this.xLeft = xL;
this.xRight = xR;
this.yTop = yT;
this.yBottom = yB;
}



Button.prototype.checkClicked = function()
{

  if(this.xLeft <= mouseX && mouseX <= this.xRight && this.yTop <= mouseY && mouseY <= this.yBottom)
  {

     return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: You should make your code more readable - less spaces between lines, correct indentation. This is just unreadable

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The basic code for playing HTML5 audio also with controls:

```js
var i = 0; // song index
var songList = [
    'songs/loop1.mp3', 'songs/loop2.mp3', 'songs/loop3.mp3', 'songs/loop4.mp3',
    'songs/loop5.mp3', 'songs/loop6.mp3', 'songs/loop7.mp3', 'songs/loop8.mp3'
];

// create audio element
var ae = document.createElement('audio');
ae.id = 'audioplayer';
ae.src = songList[0];
document.body.appendChild(ae);
// create controls
var btnPlay = document.createElement('button');
var btnPrev = document.createElement('button');
var btnNext = document.createElement('button');
var testDiv = document.createElement('div');
btnPlay.innerHTML = 'Play/Pause';
btnPrev.innerHTML = 'Previous song';
btnNext.innerHTML = 'Next song';
testDiv.id = "test";
document.body.appendChild(btnPlay);
document.body.appendChild(btnPrev);
document.body.appendChild(btnNext);
document.body.appendChild(testDiv);

//add event handlers
ae.onplay = function () {
    testDiv.innerHTML = 'Now playing #' + (i+1) + ' ' + songList[i];
};
ae.onended = function(){
    NextSong();
};
btnPlay.onclick = function() {
    if (ae.paused) ae.play();
    else ae.pause();
};
btnPrev.onclick = PrevSong;
btnNext.onclick = NextSong;
ae.play();

function PrevSong() {
    i = (i > 0)? i - 1 : songList.length - 1; // choose previous index
    ae.setAttribute("src", songList[i]);
    ae.play();
}
function NextSong() {
    i = (i < songList.length - 1)? i + 1 : 0; // choose next index
    ae.setAttribute("src", songList[i]);
    ae.play();
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/1/

HTML5 audio tag and mp3 playback was not supported in IE8 and older versions of Firefox, so for backward compatibility you should use some [flash-based fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681856/html5-audio-tag-flash-fall-back#11707538).

Example of working script [with the flash object](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/) is here: http://pastebin.com/WDzEQGtn

Answer (score 0):

Where is `checkClicked` defined? Seems like the call to that function does not operate correctly.

You didn't show us the binding of the click on the buttons, but anyways I would bind each button separately, so you won't need to check which button was clicked.